# Keyboard shortcut for transfer function model symbol

Tags: control-systems, notation

I am wondering if there is any keyboard shortcut to type transfer function model symbol as in the picture below.

I would like to plot root locus of that function but I can't figure out how to type the transfer function model symbol.

[image]

Comment: Like almost everything in Mathematica, this is a function. It's name is `TransferFunctionModel` and is used as `TransferFunctionModel[{{{k (1 + s)}}, ((-1 + s) s) (16 + 4 s + s^2)}, s]`

Comment: @bill I have the feeling the OP wants to know how you get this fancy input with that scripted capital T there. The examples given in the documentation suggest that you could do something like that. `Transpose` can be written similarly fancy by entering esc-tr-esc after a matrix, so the suggestion might be that a similar trick is possible for a transfer function or a statespace matrix.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries, yes that is what I want. However, from the answer I there is no such a thing to do it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like almost everything in Mathematica, this is a function. It's name is `TransferFunctionModel` and is used as

```
TransferFunctionModel[{{{k (1 + s)}}, ((-1 + s) s) (16 + 4 s + s^2)}, s]
```

If you find yourself using it a lot, one thing you can do it to define your own "shortcut".

```
tf[f_, s_] := TransferFunctionModel[f, s];
```

Now you can use the `tf` shortcut at will:

```
tf[{{{k (1 + s)}}, ((-1 + s) s) (16 + 4 s + s^2)}, s]
```

The prefix syntax also works:

```
tf @@ {{{{k (1 + s)}}, ((-1 + s) s) (16 + 4 s + s^2)}, s}
```

as does the infix syntax:

```
{{{k (1 + s)}}, ((-1 + s) s) (16 + 4 s + s^2)}~tf~s
```

Comment: Thanks for the shortcuts. How can you write the fraction like that?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. If you evaluate any of the above, it appears in the notebook just as in your image.

Comment: I mean this fraction {{{k (1 + s)}}, ((-1 + s) s) (16 + 4 s + s^2)}. Is there a guideline about how it work?

Comment: It's in the form of a list: {{numerator polynomial}, denominator polynomial}. Look at the help file for TransferFunctionModel for a bunch of examples. If you want alternative ways to enter the fraction, check out the "Basic Math Assistant" under the Palettes menu.

Comment: Thanks. I just confused about the fraction as a list.

Answer (score 4):

You can use evaluate in place (keyboard short cut on OSX is <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>). Here is a short animation:

[image]